# Interpretation on correlation and lasso regression

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients, lasso

Suppose that we have a feature set of 100 variables and we do not know exactly if they are useful/interesting all of them.  We first conduct a correlation analysis between each of variable and outcome (y). For example: corr(x1,y), corr(x2,y), corr(x3,y), ..., corr(x100,y)

We observe that 70 of our variables are correlated. Then we apply linear regression (with lasso) to the correlated ones to create a prediction of y model. When we investigate the coeff. of each variable, we observe that only 5 of the features have a weight different from zero. Therefore, we can say that the rest 70-5=65 variables are not interesting while predicting y.

What should be our interpretation? If they are correlated, what is the reason of being useless variables for my model? I do not understand. For me, the correlated ones should be significant to the model. Maybe the reason is to keep the lambda of lasso high. The model will try to decrease the weights as much as possible? Or maybe there is a collinearity issue between variables? If yes, do I need to check the correlation of all variables in a paired way (too much calculation). Could there be any other reasoning behind this observation?

Comment: If you have enough of a penalty, you can make all of the coefficients be zero. If you have little penalty, you can wind up with the same coefficients as you’d get from unpenalized regression (this used to be a trick to get Python’s SKLearn library to do unpenalized regression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, excluding $X$s that have low or zero correlation to $y$ from the model may not be smart, as it is possible that they are important in a multiple regression even if they are not in simple regressions. There are examples where $y$ is only weakly correlated with each of $x_1$ and $x_2$, but $y$ is almost completely determined by a linear combination of $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Second, how many variables get nonzero coefficients in lasso depends on penalty intensity. As Dave mentions in a comment, you can get all of the variables to have nonzero coefficients with a sufficiently weak penalty and none of them have nonzero coefficients with a sufficiently strong penalty. Cross validation is a popular way of choosing penalty intensity. If your tuning target is minimization of prediction loss on the left-out folds, you will only keep these regressors which help achieve the target. It should produce a model that does well in out-of-sample forecasting as measured by the loss function used in tuning.

> Or maybe there is a collinearity issue between variables? If yes, do I need to check the correlation of all variables in a paired way (too much calculation).

Having multicollinear or highly correlated regressors will make it likely that some of them get kicked out, as they are not contributing to reduction of prediction loss to a noteworthy degree, but their estimation variance is contributing to *increased* prediction loss. You do not need to check the correlation of all pairs of variables, however. First, lasso does the job for you by kicking out whatever variables are unhelpful in minimizing prediction loss. Second, pairwise correlations do not tell the whole story, with larger groups of variables (triples and larger) potentially being near or fully collinear, making one or more variables in the group more or less redundant in prediction. (This is analogous to the argument made in the first paragraph.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I think that I got the idea about -not removing a feature based on its unique correlation result with the outcome- and the idea about -possibility of getting full zero or full nonzero coefficients by selecting a very high or low penalty intensity, respectively-.

Comment: @MasA, sounds great!

Comment: I was just slightly confused on that part "If your tuning target is minimization of prediction loss on the left-out folds, you will only keep these regressors which help achieve the target. It should produce a model that does well in out-of-sample forecasting as measured by the loss function used in tuning." What do you mean by "regressors" (whole model, coeffs, or coeff of each variable?). And can you clarify this a bit more please: "It should produce a model that does well in out-of-sample forecasting as measured by the loss function used in tuning"

Comment: @MasA, by *regressors* I mean variables on the right hand side of the model. There are synonyms such as features, predictors, explanatory variables and more. Regarding the second thing, if you tune a model for a certain target, as a result you would normally obtain a model that gets as close to the target as possible (within the bounds considered of the tuning parameter). Or in other words, you should get roughly what you tune for.

Comment: Variable or feature is what I use instead of regressor. I got it, thank you. For the second, it's like observing a less generalizable model, a model that fits very well on training data but can have difficulties on testing.

Comment: @MasA, cross validation when properly done ensures that such models are highly unlikely to be selected.